# ImportError: No module named my_package when running a Python 2.7 script out of a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, importerror, python-venv

Why am I getting an `ImportError: No module named my_package` error when trying to import a module within a package in my Python project? The project structure looks like this:

```
Projectfolder
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── my_module.py
    └── my_module.pyc
```

main.py:

```py
    import sys
    import os

    # Get the path to the parent directory of ProjectFolder
    parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

    # Add the parent directory to the Python path
    sys.path.append(parent_dir)

    # Import my_module from my_package
    from my_package import my_module as test

    # Call the doSomething() function
    test.doSomething()

    # Print "done"
    print("done")
```

my_module.py:

```py
def doSomething():
    print("Hello World")
    return True
```

I start by activating the virtual environment with "source ./rosbag_auto_V2_7/bin/activate". Then I attempt to run the package with "python -m /home/user/PYTHON_DEV/ROSBag_Automation/ProjectFolder/main".

The code in `main.py` tries to import `my_package.my_module` and call `test.doSomething()`, but I get then get the following error:
 ImportError: No module named my_packag`e

It works as expected when I run `python /home/user/PYTHON_DEV/ROSBag_Automation/ProjectFolder/main.py`, it's only when I run with the module option -m that it throws the error.

I don't know enough about Python and virtual environments in general; what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `-m`.  Just `python .../main.py`.

Comment: @TimRoberts It does work without -m, but for the benefit of my understanding I want to know why it doesn't work with the -m and how I can properly resolve it.

Comment: Your `-m` method doesn't work at all in Python 3.  I see that it does work in Python 2.  You tagged Python 2 -- is there a reason you are using an antique?

Comment: @TimRoberts that's a different kettle of fish altogether; I'm limited to using a system running Ubuntu 16.04 for a project I'm working on, and furthermore on this system, my Python 2.7 venv installs PyYaml just fine but if I try to install PyYaml in my 3.5 venv it doesn't work at all. For the work I'm doing, another package depends on 'yaml' so I'm just making do with 2.7 if it works for now.

Comment: For what it's worth, I set up an environment exactly like yours, with a folder `xxx` containing an `__init__.py` and a `main.py`, and I had `main.py` do `print(__file__)`.  If I do `python2 -m xxx/main`, it prints out the correct location. So, I cannot duplicate the problem.  I certainly does  NOT work with Python 3.